# How to use object created from another method in JAva?

Tags: java, class, methods

Hi I'm trying to pass `objectA` and `objectB` that I created from method `ListA()` and `ListB()` to the `DoSomething` method, can someone please guide me on how to do this?

```java
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
myclass test = new myclass();
test.ListA(args[0]);
test.ListB(args[1]);            
test.DoSomething(objectA, objectB);
}

public void ListA(String aaa){
objectA = Sting[];
//other codes goes here...
}   

public void ListB(String bbb){
objectB = Sting[];
//other codes goes here...
}

public static void DoSomething(List<String>objectA, List<String>objectB}{
//other codes goes here...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just return the objects you created to use it with `DoSomething` function?

Hi I'm trying to pass objectA and objectB that I created from method ListA() and List B() to the DoSomething method, can someone please guide me on how to do this?

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
myclass test = new myclass();
List<String> objectA = test.ListA(args[0]);
List<String> objectB = test.ListB(args[1]);         
test.DoSomething(objectA, objectB);
}

public List<String> ListA(String aaa){
List<String> generatedA;
//Generate your object...
return generatedA;
}   

public List<String> ListB(String bbb){
List<String> generatedB;
//Generate your object...
return generatedB;
}

public static void DoSomething(List<String>objectA, List<String>objectB}{
//other codes goes here...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll want the `ListA` and `ListB` methods to return their values and then pass those to the `DoSomething` method.

A beginners tutorial on Java methods here: [homeandlearn](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/java_methods.html)
and here: [Java Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html)

Comment: Or alternatively store the values within a class itself.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to pass them you should either return:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    myclass test = new myclass();    
    test.DoSomething(test.ListA(args[0]), test.ListB(args[1]));
}

public List<String> ListA(String aaa){
    objectA = String[];
    //other codes goes here...
}   

public List<String> ListB(String bbb){
    objectB = String[];
    //other codes goes here...
}

public static void DoSomething(List<String>objectA, List<String>objectB}{
    //other codes goes here...
}
```

Or make them members:

```
List<String> objectA;
List<String> objectB;

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
myclass test = new myclass();
test.ListA(args[0]);
test.ListB(args[1]);        
test.DoSomething();
}

public List<String> ListA(String aaa){
this.objectA = Sting[];
//other codes goes here...
}   

public List<String> ListB(String bbb){
this.objectB = String[];
//other codes goes here...
}

public static void DoSomething(}{
   this.objectA
   this.objectB
//other codes goes here...
}
```